# Generate a random UIColor

Tags: objective-c, uicolor

I try to get a random color for UILabel...

```
- (UIColor *)randomColor
{
    int red = arc4random() % 255 / 255.0;
    int green = arc4random() % 255 / 255.0;
    int blue = arc4random() % 255 / 255.0;
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];
    NSLog(@"%@", color);
    return color;
}
```

And use it:

```
[mat addAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [self randomColor]} range:range];
```

But color is always black. What is wrong?

Comment: Guys please follow this link.its working perfect. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999303/random-color-in-ios

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Because you have assigned the colour values to `int` variables. Use `float` 
(or `CGFloat`) instead. Also (as [@stackunderflow's said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21130495/1187415)), the remainder must
be taken modulo 256 in order to cover the whole range `0.0 ... 1.0`:

```
CGFloat red = arc4random() % 256 / 255.0;
// Or (recommended):
CGFloat red = arc4random_uniform(256) / 255.0;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `arc4random_uniform(256) / 255.0`? Because `arc4random_uniform` returns an integer less than upper bound. So in your case r, g or b will never be 1.0 (0xFF)

Comment: @ElegyD: You are completely right, that's why I had added the final remark *"See also stackunderflow's answer about the range of possible values."* – I have edited the answer now to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 48):

```
[UIColor colorWithHue:drand48() saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0];
```

or in Swift:

```
UIColor(hue: CGFloat(drand48()), saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
```

Feel free to randomise or adjust saturation and brightness to your liking.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a swift version, made into a `UIColor` extension:

```
extension UIColor {
    class func randomColor(randomAlpha: Bool = false) -> UIColor {
        let redValue = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) / 255.0;
        let greenValue = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) / 255.0;
        let blueValue = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) / 255.0;
        let alphaValue = randomAlpha ? CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) / 255.0 : 1;

        return UIColor(red: redValue, green: greenValue, blue: blueValue, alpha: alphaValue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

**Swift** solution using a class var `random`:

```
extension UIColor {
    class var random: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: .random(in: 0...1), green: .random(in: 0...1), blue: .random(in: 0...1), alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Use just like any other in-built `UIColor` class variable (`.red`, `.blue`, `.white`, etc.), for example:

```
view.backgroundColor = .random
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for..! However, because it's actually making a new color every time it's called I think it'd be better as a `func random() -> UIColor`

Answer (score 9):

try this

```
CGFloat hue = ( arc4random() % 256 / 256.0 );  //  0.0 to 1.0
CGFloat saturation = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5; // 0.5 to 1.0, away from white
CGFloat brightness = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5; // 0.5 to 1.0, away from black
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:1];
```

Answer (score 6):

The following works on iOS 12

```
NSInteger aRedValue = arc4random()%255;
NSInteger aGreenValue = arc4random()%255;
NSInteger aBlueValue = arc4random()%255;

UIColor *randColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:aRedValue/255.0f green:aGreenValue/255.0f blue:aBlueValue/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

Comment: Probably doesn't matter for most cases, but `% 256` will yield 0...255 inclusive.  `% 255` will never yield 255 or 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

```
// RGB
UIColor *randomRGBColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:arc4random()%256/256.0 
                                                 green:arc4random()%256/256.0 
                                                  blue:arc4random()%256/256.0 
                                                 alpha:1.0];

// HSB
UIColor *randomHSBColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithHue:arc4random()%256/256.0 
                                            saturation:(arc4random()%128/256.0)+0.5 
                                            brightness:(arc4random()%128/256.0)+0.5 
                                                 alpha:1.0];
```

Answer (score 1):

`arc4random() % 255 / 255.0` will always be truncated to 0 because `arc4random()%255` will be an integer between 0 and 254 inclusive, and dividing by 255.0 and casting to an int will always result in 0.  You should save the result as a float instead.

(Also you should use `arc4random()%256` if you wish to select randomly from all possible colors.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet:

```
CGFloat redLevel    = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
CGFloat greenLevel  = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
CGFloat blueLevel   = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: redLevel
                                            green: greenLevel
                                             blue: blueLevel
                                            alpha: 1.0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Removes duplication of the 3 `arc4random` lines :)

```
static func randomColor() -> UIColor {
    let random = {CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) / 255.0}
    return UIColor(red: random(), green: random(), blue: random(), alpha: 1)
}
```