# Random color in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, colors

I want to make my Navbar a different color each time its loaded. I have placed the following code in my viewDidApear:

```
CGFloat hue = ( arc4random() % 256 / 256.0 );  //  0.0 to 1.0
CGFloat saturation = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;  //  0.5 to 1.0, away from white
CGFloat brightness = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;  //  0.5 to 1.0, away from black
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:1];

self.navigationBar.barTintColor = color;
```

the problem is that the color range is too wide.

I would like it to only select the colors that you see in this photo:

[image]

Is it possible using this code? + if not how would i create a similar one that chooses a random color from a few that I have defined.

Thanks you for you help.

Comment: Those are not random colors. Those are 12 specific colors.

Comment: My bad, question needed to be better defined.I wanted to vote you answer up but it was deleted. it worked, colors weren't exactly the same but it was a very good start for me. Thank you!

Comment: I deleted my answer after I realized the colors weren't all exactly the ones I listed.

Comment: Thank you anyway! :) Do you maybe know how I would be able to find the correct values? e.g how do i know what @X is the Green Secondary in the photo? I will do the rest :)

Comment: Sorry, just realized what a silly question it is the Hue value. Thank you! your solution worked!.

Comment: http://www.amarendrasingh.in/swift/swift-3-uicolor-utilities-random-hex-color-codes-random-uicolor/  take a look here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a copy / paste solution using your exact colors.

```
// Declare somewhere in your code
typedef struct _Color {
    CGFloat red, green, blue;
} Color;

static Color _colors[12] = {
    {237, 230, 4},  // Yellow just to the left of center
    {158, 209, 16}, // Next color clockwise (green)
    {80, 181, 23},
    {23, 144, 103},
    {71, 110, 175},
    {159, 73, 172},
    {204, 66, 162},
    {255, 59, 167},
    {255, 88, 0},
    {255, 129, 0},
    {254, 172, 0},
    {255, 204, 0}
};

- (UIColor *)randomColor {
    Color randomColor = _colors[arc4random_uniform(12)];
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:(randomColor.red / 255.0f) green:(randomColor.green / 255.0f) blue:(randomColor.blue / 255.0f) alpha:1.0f];
}
```

**NOTE**: You should use `arc4random_uniform()` instead of `arc4random()` to avoid modulo bias (although not all that important in this case).

Comment: Thank you! i get an Error: undecleard identifier randomColor in the - (UIColor *)randomColor { line.

Comment: Make sure that `Color` struct and the static array of colors `_colrors[12]` are declared before the `-(UIColor *)randomColor` method. Preferably somewhere at the top of the file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I don't seem to be able to make it work. still have the same issue :/ undecleard identifier randomColor

Comment: Please make sure that the rest of your code is sound (all brackets are in place, etc). Try moving the `randomColor` method around in your code to see if another issue comes up. I compiled and ran the posted solution code without any issues.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem (missing bracket). Sorry im new to coding. Thank you very much! Got 2 working solutions :)

Answer (score 1):

UIColor

Here's the code for this :

```
-(UIColor *)randomColor
{
   CGFloat hue = ( arc4random() % 256 / 256.0 );
   CGFloat saturation = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;
   CGFloat brightness = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;
   UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:1];
   return color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
NSArray *hues = @[ @76, @98, @160, @217, @292, @318, @327, @21, @30, @41, @48, @58 ];
NSNumber *hue = hues[arc4random_uniform(hues.count)];
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:[hue doubleValue] / 360.0 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Thank you @Rmaddy