# Background Colour Continuous Change - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, colors, background-color

How to make `UIView` background colour continuous changing like an `Instagram` log-in screen has as shown in the images without load in the memory.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you explicitly animate a CALayer's backgroundColor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518192/how-do-you-explicitly-animate-a-calayers-backgroundcolor)

Comment: you can use NSTimer ?

Answer (score 0):

To change the background color you just do:

```
    self.view.backgroundColor=yourColor;
```

and to change this continuously you can use a timer.IF you have a an array colors for the background, store the colors in an array.

```
   NSArray *colorArray=@[colo1,color2....colorn];
```

You can also generate a [random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130433/generate-a-random-uicolor) color and pass it to the view background.In that case you can just do(In this case, you don't have to store the colors in an array)

```
      self.view.backgroundColor=metodThatReturnsRandomColor.
```

OR, declare the timer to call the changeColor  method every 1.0 sec .

```
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer * timerIvar;


 self.timerIvar  = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(changeColor) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and the method would be:

```
-(void)changeColor{
         if(x<colorArray.count){
        self.view.backgroundColor=colorArray[x];
        }else{
          x=0;
       }
        x++;
  }
```

The same logic applies for images/ [gradient colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074539/programmatically-create-a-uiview-with-color-gradient).

and remember on viewWillDisappear

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  ...
  [self.timerIvar invalidate];
 self.timerIvar = nil;
}
```

Comment: Well this will look kind of awful, or you will have to have a really huge array with all color gradations

Comment: It would be better to create a color gradient in the loop instead of picking it up from an array. Otherwise it would look like a cheap neon sign, changing colors.

Comment: I don't think storing colors would create a memory issue as long as you manage it properly. @s1ddok

Comment: I agrre @NSNoob. Unless the OP has a special requirement of colors, he can create the colors in a loop. If he has a specific set of interests, then storing them in an array would be the simpler solution.